Regular expression equivalent in C++
The python code:
def extractText(self):
    text = self.datum_buffer
    if re.match(r'[ \t\r\n]*"', text, flags=re.DOTALL):
        lines = []
        for m in re.finditer(r'[ \t]*(?!\\)"(?P<text>([^"\\]|\\(?!\\)")*)(?!\\)"[ \t]*\r?\n?', text, flags=re.DOTALL):
            lines.append(m.group('text'))
        text = ''.join(lines)
    return text

Input text is:
"------${session.boundary}\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image_name\"; filename=\"${command.uploaded_filename}\"\r\n\r\n${command.image_raw_bytes}\r\n------${session.boundary}--"

Output desired:
------${session.boundary}
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_name"; filename="${command.uploaded_filename}"

${command.image_raw_bytes}
------${session.boundary}--

I tried to convert the regex pattern, but it was not resulting in desired output.
std::string extractText() {
    std::string result = this->datum_buffer;
    std::string extractedText = "";
    // Check if text starts with optional whitespace followed by a double quote
    if (std::regex_search(result, std::regex("[ \t\r\n]*\""))) {
        std::regex pattern("\"([^\"]*[\r\n]*)\"");
        std::smatch matches;

        while (std::regex_search(result, matches, pattern)) {
            std::string match = matches[1];
                    
            extractedText += match;
            result = matches.suffix().str();
        }
     }
            
     if (extractedText.empty())
         extractedText = result;
     return extractedText;
}

Output from this function:
------${session.boundary}
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=; filename=\

${command.image_raw_bytes}
------${session.boundary}--

I have updated the input and output desired

You need to use raw string literals (R"(...)") otherwise \t is interpreted as a tab escape character.

In that case the result is same

Your input text doesn't contain a single instance of " so that does not surprise me. Your Python regexp is also completely different. What are you trying to do?

Also, if your raw string is supposed to contain (, ", and ), you might want do use extra string delimiters

Your Python code looks like grabs everything between "" so I don't see how that matches your desired output...

I updated the input text, there were quotes missing

Please provide [mcve]. Current form of your question is not clear. This sequence in "input text": &#x0D;&#x0A; vs you try match with RE containing \r\n makes we wonder if you are asking a proper question at all. (Python code also do not make sense for this input string). Should you first decode xml escape sequence or handle xml escape sequence in RE?

Starting point for [mcve].

I have updated the input text

Your python code doesn't seem to work too: https://ideone.com/2f601D

Sorry for the error on my side i have updated the input and desired output

Is this actually achieving anything other than splitting on \r\n? I can't see any other effect in the output...

This is utterly trivial if you don't use a regular expression.
